# AJAX load when reach bottom of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't figure this problem out.

I use this JS call to load ajax content when I arrive at the bottom of the page:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height()  ) {
```

and it works well, but now I want to change for loading the content when I reach the bottom of my container... I am trying this:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#postswrapper').offset().top +     $('#postswrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
```

It loads the content when I reach the bottom of the container, but it loads it like 5 times... It's like as if it does a loop 5 times each time.

I want it to load ONCE, then when I go back DOWN the page and I reach the "NEW BOTTOM" of the container, load data 1 more time...etc

I tried many variables, but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

FULL AJAX CODE

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#postswrapper').offset().top + $('#postswrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {



        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: "loadmore.php",
            method: "get",
            data: { page: pageNumber, perpage: perPage, search: "<?=$search?>", blogtag: "<?=$blogtag?>"},
            success: function(html)
                    {
                        if(html)
                        {
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();

                            pageNumber++;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                        }

                    }

        }); // close AJAX

        }  // close if()
}); // close $(window)
```

Comment: Can't really tell what's going on without looking at your AJAX code...

Comment: I've updated the post with the full ajax code

Answer (score 0):

Scroll top is executed few times after you have the set true for the condition:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#postswrapper').offset().top + $('#postswrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight)
```

Here is a test fiddle for the window scroll, it always fires when you move the scroll and your condition does not limit the inner scope to execute only once.

[test scrool event](http://jsfiddle.net/zdrsh/t7obg4qy/)

Edit: simplest way is to use a lock while the ajax request is executing and while you are updating the UI with new content.

Comment: ok, but what should I use to execute only once instead of a few times?

Answer (score 0):

Why build something like this yourself when there are plenty of libraries out there? Just use an infinite scroll library that meets your needs. As you already use jQuery:
http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

But that's not the answer to your question. You should add a `boolean` to check if you're already loading new content. Let's say: `loading`. Initially set this boolean to `false`. If you request new data, set the boolean to true and in the check scroll statement add a check for this boolean. After adding the newly loaded content set the boolean to false again.

Fully working code:

```
var loading = false;

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if(!loading && $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('#postswrapper').offset().top + $('#postswrapper').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight)) {

        loading = true;

        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php",
            method: "get",
            data: {
                page: pageNumber,
                perpage: perPage, 
                search: "<?=$search?>", 
                blogtag: "<?=$blogtag?>"
            },
            success: function(html) {
                if(html) {
                    $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();

                    pageNumber++;
                    loading = false;
                } else {
                    $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
            }
        }); // close AJAX
    }  // close if()
}); // close $(window)
```